# How to filter YouTube search result by language?

Tags: youtube

I want to get video result in specific language.

I want want a filler like that:

```
test, lang:ru
```

[image]
Didnt work

Or maybe in url parameter filter:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=test&lang=ru

Didn't work too.

Can somebody give me an advise on how to filter YouTube results by language.

Comment: As of 2023 it is still not posible to filter YouTube search results by language. There is no built-in feature or URL parameter that allows you to do this. I guess you could jsut narrow down your search results to a specific language by name of the language or country to your search query, or using keywords that are specific to the language you are looking for. But no built-in function exists.